# PL/pgSQL anonymous code block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In PostgreSQL 9.0 I have this PLPGSQL anonymous code block:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE
        bigobject integer;
    BEGIN
        SELECT lo_creat(-1) INTO bigobject;
        ALTER LARGE OBJECT bigobject OWNER TO postgres;
        INSERT INTO files (id, "mountPoint", data, comment) VALUES (15, '/images/image.png', bigobject, 'image data');
        SET search_path = pg_catalog;
        SELECT pg_catalog.lo_open(bigobject, 131072);
        SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\\x000001000100101010000000000028010000160000002800000010000000200000000100040');
        SELECT pg_catalog.lo_close(0);
        REVOKE ALL ON LARGE OBJECT bigobject FROM PUBLIC;
        REVOKE ALL ON LARGE OBJECT bigobject FROM postgres;
        GRANT ALL ON LARGE OBJECT bigobject TO postgres;
        GRANT ALL ON LARGE OBJECT bigobject TO "com.ektyn.eshops.myuser";
    END
$$;
```

but it fails:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "bigobject"
LINE 6:   ALTER LARGE OBJECT bigobject OWNER TO postgres;
                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "bigobject"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 103
```

and I can't find mistake in code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There must be an **oid constant** in `ALTER LARGE OBJECT oid ...`. Try this workaround:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE
        bigobject integer;
    BEGIN
        SELECT lo_creat(-1) INTO bigobject;
        EXECUTE 'ALTER LARGE OBJECT ' || bigobject::text || ' OWNER TO postgres';
        ...
```

The same also applies to GRANT and REVOKE, of course.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what [@klin already cleared up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23587273/939860), you cannot use `SELECT` without a target in PL/pgSQL code. Replace it with [`PERFORM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) in those calls.

Aside: Using `"com.ektyn.eshops.myuser"` as name for a role is a terrible idea. Use legal, lower case identifiers that don't have to be double-quoted.

Comment: My answer is surely helpful, but klin addresses the primary issue in your question. So the accept should probably go to his answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is an artifact of the fact that PostgreSQL has two completely different kinds of SQL statements internally - *plannable* (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`) and *unplannable* (everything else) statements.

Only plannable statements support query parameters.

PL/pgSQL implements variable substitutions into statements, like your `bigobject`, using query parameters.

Because they aren't supported for non-plannable statements, no substitution is performed. So PL/pgSQL tries to execute the statement literally, as if you'd typed:

```
ALTER LARGE OBJECT bigobject OWNER TO postgres;
```

directly at the `psql` prompt. It does not detect this as an error.

To work around this, use `EXECUTE ... FORMAT`, e.g.

```
EXECUTE format('ALTER LARGE OBJECT %s OWNER TO postgres', bigobject);
```

See [this related answer about `COPY`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22962205/398670).