# Function argument not interpreted inside body

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a PL/pgSQL function in PostgreSQL 9.3.6, but there is weird behavior when using the passed argument inside function body. Here is the 'very simple' function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.test (myarg text) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  entity text;
  buffer text;
BEGIN
    CREATE ROLE myarg;
    RETURN myarg;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So, if for instance `myarg` equals 'test':

- A role named 'myarg' is created (WRONG)
- 'test' is returned (CORRECT)

I searched for hours why this could be and no clue... security parameter? Why is `myarg` not interpreted for creating roles?

Testing with phpPgAdmin through sql files if this has any impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE ROLE %I', myarg);
```

[Here you can find an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586848/pl-pgsql-anonymous-code-block/23587273#23587273) (especially read Craig's answer).

---

As Erwin stated (thanks), %I is safer than %s. Anyway, *myarg* should be verified before the function call. Try for example

```
SELECT myschema.test('something; stupid; here;')
```

Comment: Be sure to escape `myarg` as identifier in this context (a role name) or you are open to SQL injection. Use `%I` with `format()` unless the identifier is safely escaped already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349