# PostgreSQL using variable name as string literal

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

In this script I expected the output to be:

```
NOTICE:  00000: Outside value is: hello
NOTICE:  00000: Inside value is: hello
```

but the output was:

```
NOTICE:  00000: Outside value is: hello
NOTICE:  00000: Inside value is: my_variable
```

Why is PostgreSQL using the name of the variable as a string literal when passing it to the function? Notice I didn't put single quotes around the variable name, so I was not expecting it to be interpreted as a string literal.

Here is the script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table(my_field text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Inside value is: %', TG_ARGV[0];
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $$
DECLARE
    my_variable text := 'hello';
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Outside value is: %', my_variable;
    CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
        AFTER INSERT ON my_table 
        FOR EACH ROW 
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_function(my_variable);
END
$$;

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('some value');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) (emphasis added):

> ***arguments***
>
> An optional comma-separated list of arguments to be provided to the function when the trigger is executed. The arguments are **literal string constants**. Simple names and numeric constants can be written here, too, but they will all be converted to strings.

CREATE TRIGGER is a DDL command in which variables are not known. You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to use a variable in this case. See also [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23587273/1995738)

Comment: Ha! Thanks, I looked at a different documentation page that didn't make it that clear.